# Tracking custom image links on WordPress website by Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I recently developed a WordPress website where I give the option to the admin to upload an image and give a link to be shown as the advertisement in the front end. 
Basically, the image is clickable and links to the link provided by the admin.

What i want now is to track the clicks on these advertisements via Google Analytics. Is this possible? 
I am new to Google Analytics and do not have much idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Attach onclick event to document only and catch clicks on all elements.
  $(document.body).click(function(event) {
    // Catch the closest surrounding link of a clicked element.
    $(event.target).closest("a,area").each(function() {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Image Click', $('img', this).attr('alt'), $(this).attr('href')]);
    });
  });  
});

})(jQuery);
```

Yeah is possible you can track the image click via google analytics See this reference for more info.
http://techatitsbest.com/blog/image-click-tracking-google-analytics-events

http://www.seotakeaways.com/event-tracking-guide-google-analytics-simplified-version/